# Error: expected primary expression

Tags: c++

I keep getting the error "expected primary-expression before ')' token.

This is the function that I keep getting the error on and I cannot find what is wrong

```
bool Player::hasWeapon(){
   for(std::list<Item*>::iterator it=inventory.begin(); it!=inventory.end(); ++it)
   {
       if((it*)->getItemType()=="Weapon")
       {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: `if((it*)->getItemType()=="Weapon")` should be `if(it->getItemType()=="Weapon")`

Comment: You should add that as an answer.

Comment: The compiler identifies the *exact line number* in the error message, which tells you where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if((it*)->getItemType()=="Weapon")
     ^

if((*it)->getItemType()=="Weapon")
```

suggestion: use a compilation output (there is a line number of error there) and a debugger

Comment: How does a debugger help when it won't compile?

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. The funny thing is that I did that exact same thing right in other parts of my code, but I guess I just didn't notice that I was putting the * in the wrong place.